# How to fix this python error? OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Tags: python

it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Public\SoundLog\Code\Código Python\SoundLog\Plugins\NoisePlugin.py", line 113, in onPaint
    dc.DrawLine(valueWI, valueHI, valueWF, valueHF)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_gdi.py", line 3177, in DrawLine
    return _gdi_.DC_DrawLine(*args, **kwargs)
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

How can I avoid this to happen?

Comment: Easy answer: don't pass infinity into the DrawLine function.

Comment: I'd probably start by looking at the loops and see if it is going beyond the range.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the four values `valueWI, valueHI, valueWF, valueHF` is set to float infinity.  Just truncate it to something reasonable, e.g., for a general and totally local solution, change your `DrawLine` call to:

```
ALOT = 1e6
vals = [max(min(x, ALOT), -ALOT) for x in (valueWI, valueHI, valueWF, valueHF)]
dc.DrawLine(*vals)
```

best, of course, would be to understand which of the values is infinity, and why -- and fix that.  But, this preferable course is very application-dependent, and entirely depends on the code leading to the computation of those values, which you give us absolutely no clue about, so it's hard for us to offer very specific help about this preferable option!-)

Comment: Hi @Alex Martelli, i am also facing similar issues while trying to apply log transformation in rfm output. I tried ur suggestion. but still i m getting error

Answer (score 9):

OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

```
def round_int(x):
    if x in [float("-inf"),float("inf")]: return float("nan")
    return int(round(x))

# TEST
print(round_int(174.919753086))
print(round_int(0))
print(round_int(float("inf")))
print(round_int(float("-inf")))

175
0
nan
nan
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to post some code to get a definitive answer, but I would guess that one of your float values is unset. As such it could hold any value such as `NaN` (Not a Number), but in this case it's set to infinity. This can't be cast to integer, hence the error.

It will be being cast to an integer, as ultimately the screen is an integer space (1600 x 1200 pixels for example).