# I am new to k-means clustering and I am trying to run a code about clustering car types but there errors occurring to me

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn import svm  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
%matplotlib inline 
dataset = pd.read_csv("cars.csv")
#importing the dataset
X= dataset[dataset.columns[:-1]] #print all except last column
X=X.convert_obects(convert_numeric=True) ##show error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 
'convert_obects'
# Eliminating null values 
for i in X.columns:
    X[i]=X[i].fillna(int (X [i].mean())) 
for i in X.columns: #double check
    print(X[i].isnull().sum())
X.head()
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
wcss=[] #an array
for i in range (0,11):
    kmeans= KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)  
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_) #show error 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'inertia_'
plt.plot(range(0,11),WCSS)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```

#so I don't know what is the problem in these two errors
#Also I have imported pandas and numpy libraries

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 0):

First error is because it is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) and does no longer exists in pandas, the second seem to be because you did not fit your model. From [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html):

> ```
> inertia_ : float
>    Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center.
> ```

You first need to fit a model to get such info.

Comment: How can I fit the model, please? I am guided by a crash course that help me to write the code, and I wrote it the same that is why I do not know why there is a problem in fitting the model

Comment: add line `kmeans.fit(X)` before `wcss.append(...)`

Comment: OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Comment: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844922/how-to-fix-this-python-error-overflowerror-cannot-convert-float-infinity-to-in)