# How to treat a Log transformation to address the skewness in distribution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to apply log function onto RFM output to address the skewness in distribution. Here's the sample code for it.

```
# Apply Log Transformation
rfm_log['monetary'] = rfm_log['monetary'] + 0.0000000001
recency_log = np.log(rfm_log['recency'])
frequency_log = np.log(rfm_log['frequency'])
monetary_log = np.log(rfm_log['monetary'])

# Plot RFM distributions
plt.figure(figsize=(16,14))

# Plot distribution of R
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1); sns.distplot(recency_log)

# Plot distribution of F
plt.subplot(3, 1, 2); sns.distplot(frequency_log)

# Plot distribution of M
plt.subplot(3, 1, 3); sns.distplot(monetary_log)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Not sure, why I am getting this error

```
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-72b5d1c46051> in <module>
     11 
     12 # Plot distribution of R
---> 13 plt.subplot(3, 1, 1); sns.distplot(recency_log)
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: Try truncate it to something reasonable [How to fix this python error? OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2844954/13144143)

Comment: Tried @Alex Martelli suggestion. but still same error